# unable to query java script array in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Hi I am developing web application in angularjs. I am trying to query array in angularjs. Below is my code snippet.

```
var angulararray = [];
bindleaselistings.bindleaselistingsmethod().then(function(response) {
  angular.forEach(response.data.data.LeaseList, function(value, key) {
    angulararray.push(value);
  });
}, function(error) {});
console.log(angulararray);
debugger;
var found = $filter('filter')(angulararray, {
  id: accountnumber
}, true);
if (found.length) {
  $scope.selected = JSON.stringify(found[0]);
} else {
  $scope.selected = 'Not found';
}
```

console.log displays required array. I have attached screenshot.[image]

When i debug the `var found = $filter('filter')(angulararray, { id: accountnumber }, true);` I can see angulararray is empty. May I know am I doing anything wrong in above code? Any help would be appreciated. Thank you

Comment: Can You post all the code in Question to find  the problem.

Comment: If the account number is the variable you want to filter by, it should look like this: `var found = $filter('filter')(angulararray, accountnumber, true);`

Comment: The problem is in misunderstanding of asynchronous operations in JS

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: Thank you all. Whenever i debug angulararray is not containing any elements but in console it is displaying array. I am struggling to find out the issue

Comment: May i know is there any way i can fix this issue?

Comment: Can someone help me to understand the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with asynchronous execution of your code.The execution of your API call and the code below it, will be executed in parallel. The value of `angulararray` is empty outside the API call.  You can move your filtering inside the success callback of your API.

```
var angulararray = [];
bindleaselistings.bindleaselistingsmethod().then(function(response) {
    angular.forEach(response.data.data.LeaseList, function(value, key) {
        angulararray.push(value);
    });
var found = $filter('filter')(angulararray, {
    id: accountnumber
}, true);
}, function(error) {});
console.log(angulararray);

if (found.length) {
    $scope.selected = JSON.stringify(found[0]);
} else {
    $scope.selected = 'Not found';
}
```

Comment: Thanks Vivz. I have updated screenshot. I am not able to match accountNumber eventhough accounnumber exist in array.

Comment: I think you should use accountNumber inside the filter

Answer (score 1):

You're having an async problem. Your code needs to be run after the promise is resolved.

The reason you get the response in the console.log is because your tools show a live view of the variable. So once the variable is resolved the view in the console will change to the result of the resolved promise.

```
var angulararray = [];
bindleaselistings.bindleaselistingsmethod().then(function (response) {
    angular.forEach(response.data.data.LeaseList, function (value, key) {
        angulararray.push(value);
    });
    console.log(angulararray);
    debugger;
    var found = $filter('filter')(angulararray, {
        id: accountnumber
    }, true);
    if (found.length) {
        $scope.selected = JSON.stringify(found[0]);
    } else {
        $scope.selected = 'Not found';
    }
}, function (error) { });
```

Answer (score 0):

you could change the way u filter ur variable and have something like this:

```
 var found;
 var len = angulararray.length;
 for(var i=0; i<angulararray; i++){
  if(typeof angulararray[i]['AccountNumber'] === 'undefined') {
    $scope.selected = 'Not found';
  }
  else {
  found = angulararray[i];
  $scope.selected = JSON.stringify(found[0]);
  }
 }
```